# wp-cron.php not being executed

Tags: wordpress

Tonight I noticed that a few emails that were supposed to go out already (yesterday) were not sent.  The plugin that scheduled and sends these emails to sent via a WP Cron job.

So doing some digging into the Apache logs I cannot see one instance of wp-cron.php being called.  So somehow the script is not being excuted by Wordpress.  I do NOT have `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);` set in wp-config.php or anywhere for that matter.

No with that all said, I was able to access wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron directly from a wget command and this ran the 'jobs' and sent the emails.

So I am wondering why Wordpress may not be running wp-cron.php when the site is visited (in which it was for sure today).

I know that I want to setup a proper cron job to run the wp-cron.php on it's own in the end anyways... but I just am bugged as to why it is not working as it should be default.

Perhaps somebody can shed some light and show me something I might be missing?

Cheers

Comment: Did you set the inbuilt cron or the server cron for this ? I guess you already do knw that inbuilt cron is only triggered when someone visits a site. So, if you have triggered your cron to execute a script within a time frame condition then if a user has visited the site during that time frame, then only the cron is triggered. These emails; Are they triggered in certain time conditions ?

Comment: I am aware that they are triggered when somebody visits the site.  And I have had visitors on the site.   The emails are scheduled by a plugin.  There is one scheduled for later today - I will see if it goes.  But the Apache log file is showing nothing in terms of accessing the wp-cron.php file.  So I don't think it is being called at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I resolved it with https://wp-mix.com/wordpress-cron-not-working/ . Although now as I navigate my site I see https://example.com/?doing_wp_cron=1234567890.0987654321098765432 . This affects SEO

I hope someone can get to the root cause of the problem.

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes